# When does Niv-Mizzet's trigger resolve?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

While playing a [Niv-Mizzet, the Firemind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNiv-Mizzet%2c%20the%20Firemind%5d) EDH deck. If I cast a spell which would cause me to lose the game via drawing too many cards, but would deal lethal damage to the last opponent e.g a wheel effect with a hand larger than my library, do I draw all the cards before Niv-Mizzet's trigger resolves and lose or deal damage after each card drawn and win?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In a 2-player game, you would lose the game and the Niv-Mizzet triggers would not resolve.**

The [Wheel of Fortune](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWheel%20of%20Fortune%5d) you played would resolve as the only object on the stack. After the Wheel has finished resolving, before the damage triggers would even be put on the stack, you would lose the game for having attempted to draw from an empty library.

> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.
>
> 116.5. Each time a player would get priority, the game first performs all applicable state-based actions as a single event (see rule 704, “State-Based Actions”), then repeats this process until no state-based actions are performed. Then triggered abilities are put on the stack
>
> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 116, “Timing and Priority”), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions
>
> 704.5b If a player attempted to draw a card from a library with no cards in it since the last time state-based actions were checked, he or she loses the game.

Comment: To clarify, triggered actions are put on the stack the next time a player would get priority. Are Niv-Mizzet's triggers put on the stack first, or does the player lose first?

Comment: 603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities he or she controls on the stack in any order he or she chooses. (See rule 101.4.) Then the game once again checks for and resolves state-based actions

Comment: But that doesnt really matter since they will not resolve because the game will be over anyway (in a 2 player game)

Comment: I've just checked and 116.5 clarifies that state-based actions are checked before triggered abilities get added, so Niv's triggers never make it to the stack. A minor point that wouldn't matter in this case (the abilities would disappear when the player dies anyway), but the game rules have the potential for this to make a difference (e.g. with replacement effects for abilities).

Comment: Thanks, a game I played the other week should have gone the other way then. (the table (non of whom were judges)  ruled that the trigger happened per card). I'll make sure not to do that again!